# Ubuntu Cloud Setup without formating node HDD

Tags: cloud, maas

Is it possible to setup a Master + 2 node Ubuntu Cloud without installing anything to the nodes (booting them over network) ?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible with MAAS to do this, it's designed to provision nodes from bare metal, this includes formatting and adding it to MAAS so that services can be deployed on it.